# Pandas: Filter dataframe by difference between adjacent rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data in a dataframe.

| Timestamp | MeasureA | MeasureB | MeasureC | MeasureD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00 | 26.46 | 63.60 | 3.90 | 0.67 |
| 0.94 | 26.52 | 78.87 | 1.58 | 0.42 |
| 1.94 | 30.01 | 82.04 | 1.13 | 0.46 |
| 3.00 | 30.19 | 82.00 | 1.17 | 0.36 |
| 4.00 | 30.07 | 81.43 | 1.13 | 0.42 |
| 5.94 | 30.02 | 82.46 | 1.05 | 0.34 |
| 8.00 | 30.22 | 82.48 | 0.98 | 0.35 |
| 9.00 | 30.00 | 82.21 | 1.13 | 0.33 |
| 10.00 | 30.00 | 82.34 | 1.12 | 0.34 |

And I'd like to filter the entries using some non-uniform intervals. Let say that my intervals are `[1.0, 1.5]`

What I'm trying to achieve is that, we take the first row (`row0`), and to get the next valid row, we look at what is the next row whose `Timestamp` value is greater or equal to `row0 + 1.0`.

In this scenario, the next valid row will be the one with the `1.94` timestamp. Then, for the next valid row, we will use the next item in the intervals array. Which is `1.5`. That will make the next row the one with a `timestamp` value of `4.00`. Since `1.94 + 1.5` is equal to `3.44`.

For the next row, we go back and start from the beginning of the array of intervals.

After going through all the data, the resulting dataframe should be:

| Timestamp | MeasureA | MeasureB | MeasureC | MeasureD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00 | 26.46 | 63.60 | 3.90 | 0.67 |
| 1.94 | 30.01 | 82.04 | 1.13 | 0.46 |
| 4.00 | 30.07 | 81.43 | 1.13 | 0.42 |
| 5.94 | 30.02 | 82.33 | 1.11 | 0.35 |
| 8.00 | 30.22 | 82.48 | 0.98 | 0.35 |
| 9.00 | 30.00 | 82.21 | 1.13 | 0.33 |

Is there a way to achieve this with the existing filtering methods in pandas?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You will need loop through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
from itertools import cycle

# the interval:
A, B = 1.0, 1.5

comparing, out, last_t = cycle([B, A]), [], float("-inf")
j = next(comparing)

for i, t in zip(df.index, df.Timestamp):
    if t >= last_t + j:
        out.append(i)
        last_t = t
        j = next(comparing)

print(df.loc[out])
```

Prints:

```
   Timestamp  MeasureA  MeasureB  MeasureC  MeasureD
0       0.00     26.46     63.60      3.90      0.67
2       1.94     30.01     82.04      1.13      0.46
4       4.00     30.07     81.43      1.13      0.42
5       5.94     30.02     82.46      1.05      0.34
6       8.00     30.22     82.48      0.98      0.35
7       9.00     30.00     82.21      1.13      0.33
```

Comment: Might `df[['Timestamp']].itertuples()` be more efficient than `zip(df.index, df.Timestamp)`?

Comment: @Nick according to my timeit-benchmark `itertuples()` version is ~50x slower. This thing could probably be rewritten in `numba` to speed it up...

Comment: Wow. I would not have expected that. Thanks for testing.